# enter password into execSync when prompted

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, unix

I've set up a function that is supposed to run `mysqldump` on my database every specified time period.

```
import { execSync } from "child_process";    

// This will result in an empty file, since stdout isn't receiving any data.
execSync(`mysqldump -u root -p --databases myDatabase > Path/To/Output.sql`);

// This does not work...
execSync(process.env.MYSQL_PASS);
```

The only issue is that `mysqldump` prompts for a password shortly after being run, and thus, nothing is output.

> Enter password: (this is where it just hangs)

Is there a way to supply the terminal with a password on prompt? Or do I have to approach this differently?

**UPDATE:** The only solution I've found for this so far is to supply the password to the command line using `-p${process.env.MYSQL_PASS}`, however, as expected, this results in:

> mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

Comment: Perhaps: `sleep(1)` then provide the password?

Comment: @timgavin Nope...

Comment: another option https://github.com/ifsnop/mysqldump-php

Comment: @timgavin Check tags; I'm using Node – not PHP.